# Increase Zoom Sensitivity of PDF

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, performance

```js
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
var PDFRenderingInProgress = false
var pdfDoc = null
var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var container = document.getElementById("div-container")

var url = 'https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/mzwDIs6RTbiWZkxscEXL';


var wheelTimeoutHandler = null;
var wheelTimeout = 250 //ms

function renderPage(scale) {
    pdfDoc.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
        var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: ctx,
            viewport: viewport
        };

        if (!PDFRenderingInProgress) {
            PDFRenderingInProgress = true
            var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            renderTask.promise.then(function() {
                PDFRenderingInProgress = false
            })
        }
  });
}

function zoomWithWheel(event) {
    panzoom.zoomWithWheel(event)
    clearTimeout(wheelTimeoutHandler);
    wheelTimeoutHandler = setTimeout(function() {
        canvas.style.transform = "scale("+1/panzoom.getScale()+")"
        if (pdfDoc)
            renderPage(panzoom.getScale());
    }, wheelTimeout)
}

pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    renderPage(1);
});

var panzoom = Panzoom(container)
container.parentElement.addEventListener('wheel', zoomWithWheel)
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  direction: ltr;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
#div-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@panzoom/panzoom@4.3.2/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>



<div id="div-container">
  <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Above is a **working code which can zoom in a Web Link (PDF File) using the wheel of Your Mouse**. In this case, my PDF is at `var url = 'https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/mzwDIs6RTbiWZkxscEXL';`, may I ask how to  **increase zoom sensitivity (More Zoom per Scroll Step Size) ?** Thus Library I am using is **PDFJS LIB**. I will really appreciate any help I can get :)

Comment: @KJ, hi, thanks for dropping by :), is there a way to do it programmatically using Javascript :) ?

Comment: @KJ, yes, then the only way is to add the code that increases zoom sensitivity, but I am not sure how? I have searched the internet for answers for days but found none :), hopefully there are other people who knows how to solve this :)